# How to set all data into a new .m file and run it in another?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i would like to make a file called "SavedData.h" "SavedData.m" and store all my games saved data in these files...

How would I wire the whole process up to run in my "MainView.h" and "MainView.m"

I'm not that experienced with xcode...

The action in the MainView.m:

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {

if ([answer isEqualToString:@"Pizza Pie"]) {

//Name:Pizza Pie *SAVED
NSString *savestring = _textbox.text; 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savedstring"];
[defaults synchronize];

}
```

_textbox is my textField

and in my SavedData.m:

```
//Name:Pizza Pie
{  
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"]; 
[_textbox setText:loadstring];
}
```

How is this done?

& is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're aiming to save state to a file and restore it later (you wouldn't use source files for this, there's no compiler on the phone).  Steps are:

Put whatever you want to save in a dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myState = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
myState[@"foo"] = @"bar";
```

Get a path to where you're app is allowed to save:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *pathFile = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mystate.plist"];
```

Save:

```
[myState writeToFile:pathFile atomically:YES];
```

Read it later:

```
myState = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsofFile:pathFile];
```

You can also build a mutable dictionary this same way (replace NSDictionary in the last line with NSMutableDictionary).